# R - Remove rows where the value in one column is found twice, once each for different values in another column

Tags: r, duplicates, columnsorting

Suppose this is my input:

```
col1 <- c("A", "B", "B", "A", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D")
col2 <- c(0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1)
df <- cbind(col1,col2)
df
col1   col2
A       0
B       1 
B       0
A       0
C       1
C       1
D       0
D       1
D       1
```

I want my output to be this:

```
col1   col2
A       0
A       0
C       1
C       1
```

Duplicates in col1 are fine so long as their values in col2 are duplicated also, and these duplicates are all of the same value. When duplicates in col1 have different values in col2, I want all of these rows to be removed. I have tried standard removal of duplicates like this:

```
test <- df[duplicated(df[c(1,2)]),]
```

But it just removes everything.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `duplicated`, use `n_distinct` (number of distinct elements) after grouping in `filter` to keep only groups having single unique element in 'col2'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(col1) %>%
   filter(n_distinct(col2) == 1) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  col1   col2
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A         0
2 A         0
3 C         1
4 C         1
```

---

Or if we want a specific count, create a frequency column with `add_count`, then `filter` where the `n` values are `all` 2s after grouping by 'col1'

```
df %>% 
 add_count(col1, col2) %>% 
 group_by(col1) %>% 
 filter(all(n == 2)) %>%
 ungroup %>% 
 select(-n)
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
subset(df, col1 %in% names(which(rowSums(table(unique(df)) > 0) == 1)))
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(col1, col2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried your suggestion and got the following error:
Error in UseMethod("group_by") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'array', 'character')"

Comment: @Gotmadstacks sorry, you created a `matrix` with `cbind` as by default it is `cbind.matrix`.  You can use `df <- data.frame(col1, col2)` to create a data.frame

Comment: @Gotmadstacks also, creating a `matrix` in this data would create more problems i.e. `matrix` can have only a single type, thus your numeric column will also get transformed to character